# I get an error when using .astype() with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I get an error when trying to make a new df:

**ERROR:**

```
'A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead'
```

This is the code that gives the error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
new_df = df
bools = ['ind-debateclub', 'ind-programming_exp', 
'ind-international_exp',
'ind-entrepeneur_exp', 'ind-exact_study', 'decision']

for i in bools:
    new_df[i] = df[i].astype(int)
new_df.head()
```

I have tried it like this, but this yields the same error:

```
new_df[i] = df.loc[df[i].astype(int)]
```

The input looks like this:
[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG1pq.png)

Comment: How did you create `new_df`?  That seems to be the issue.

Comment: I have edited the question (`new_df = df`).

Comment: You have a syntax error at `'ind- international_exp'`. Are you sure this is the right code? Though maybe that's just a typo. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `new_df = df` doesn't do anything other than add a new reference to the existing dataframe. `new_df[i] = df[i].astype(int)` ... these are just two references to the same object. There is no copy for instance.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example that includes initializing `data`. If `data` is a slice of another dataframe, you'd get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `new_df = df` line to:

```
new_df = df.copy()
```

also change the `.astype()` line to:

```
new_df[i] = new_df[i].astype(int)
```

Comment: This only makes sense if `data` was already a reference to some filtered dataframe (making it a copy or view referencing some of the same data in another dataframe).